# For loop for a list to prevent vertical display

Tags: list, for-loop, formatting

```
ini_list = "[('G 02', 'UV', '2.73')]"
res = ini_list.strip('[]')
print(res)
('G 02', 'UV', '2.73')

result = res.strip('()')
print(result)
'G 02', 'UV', '2.73'
```

I have a list: 'G 02', 'UV', '2.73' and I would like to assign variables to this list
so that the outcome is as follows:

```
Element = G 02
Reason = UV
Time = 2.73
```

I have numerous lists that contain those parameters that I would like to later use to plot various things and so would like to extract each parameter from the list and associate it with the specific variable.

I tried to do it by:

```
    Results = res
    for index, Parameters in enumerate(Results):
    element = Parameters[0]
    print(element)
```

in the hopes that i could extract each item from the list to assign it a variable as mentioned above however when i print element the list prints vertically downwards and it also doesnt let me extract individual indexes.

'
G

0
2
'
,

'
U
V
'
,

'
2
.
7
3
'

how do i get it so it assigns variables to each parameter as mentioned above and so it prints as so:

```
element = G 02 
reason = UV
time = 2.73
```

Comment: What programming language are you using? This looks like python to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the `ini_list` is a string such as `ini_list = "[('G 02', 'UV', '2.73')]"` then you need `strip` and `split` methods to do your work such as following,

```
ini_list = "[('G 02', 'UV', '2.73')]"
res = ini_list.strip('[]')

result = res.strip('()')

result1 = result.split(',')

result1=[x.strip(" ") for x in result1]
result1=[x.strip("''") for x in result1]

element = result1[0]
print("element:",element)
reason =result1[1]
print("reason:",reason)
time=result1[2]
print("time:",time)
```

output:

```
element: G 02
reason: UV
time: 2.73
```

Comment: If for instance the initial list had multiple parameters such as : "[('G 02', 'UV', '2.73'), ('G 01', 'Out of Step', '3.16')]" and i wanted to group the first element of each list so that element = G 02, G01 etc and reason = UV, out of step etc and time = 2.73 and 3.16 for how many element combos there was in a list how would i go about adjusting this answer to include a for loop for the elements in the list

Comment: @LexiLigeti why your list is string`("[('G 02', 'UV', '2.73')")` and not a actual list `[('G 02', 'UV', '2.73')`.

Comment: Its been extracted from an excel spreadsheet generated by power factory. The results have been displayed in that format